# Cannot Get Data from Custom Class

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

I looked around for an answer to this because it seems simple but I could not seem to find something that suffised. I am trying to test a program I have with fake data. I created a StudentData class that possesses a attributes for a student and also has an array to hold them all.

When another class needs them they call a getStudent method (which is the only public part of this class thus far) and sends an ID number to get the name of that student back.

My problem is that I cannot figure out how to parse through the student array to match the student ID numbers with the one that was passed in. Holding the same problem, I cannot figure out how to pull the name out of a student object either.

Here is my code so far:

```
// StudentData.m

#import "StudentData.h"

@interface StudentData() {
    NSString *ID;
    NSString *firstName;
}
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray *studentArray;
@end

@implementation StudentData
@synthesize studentArray = _studentArray;

- (NSMutableArray *)studentArray {
    if(!_studentArray) _studentArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    return _studentArray;
}

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    NSArray *idA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"111", @"685", nil];
    NSArray *fnA = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Mark", @"Sam", nil];

    for(int i = 0; i < idA.count; i++) {
        StudentData *tempCurrentStudent = [[StudentData alloc] init];
        ID = [idA objectAtIndex:i];
        firstName = [fnA objectAtIndex:i];

        [self.studentArray addObject:tempCurrentStudent];
    }
}

- (NSString *)getStudentsFirstName:(NSString *)studentID {
    NSString *firstName;

    for(int i = 0; i < self.studentArray.count; i++) {
        if([studentID isEqualToString:[[self.studentArray objectAtIndex:i] self.firstName]]) { // ERROR
            fN = [[self.studentArray objectAtIndex:i] self.firstName]; // ERROR
        }
    }

    return firstName;
}

@end
```

The Error I keep getting is: **Expect ']'** and the error is pointing to the "self.firstName" lines.

If I use "[self.studentArray objectAtIndex:i].firstName;" I get the error: **Property 'firstName' not found on object of type 'id'** I even get this error if I make "firstName" a property (both local or public). This makes sense because the array is technically filled with 'id' types. I also know that unlike java I cannot use generics or anything like that.

Any help would be much appreciated and if it needs clarification please let me know! By the way this is for an ipod/ipad app if that helps at all.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Two things :

1. You're having a name conflict here. You are having a local variable called firstName and the parameter passed to your problem function has the same name.
2. `firstName`is NOT a property unless you define it as one. In this case it's just a normal local variabel. Means that you can't access it using `self.firstName` but just by `firstName`. That's one of the reason the coding guidelines say that you should name local variables starting with an underscore ( as you are already doing in the `studentArray`property). This way you can distinguish if it is a local variable or a property.

Best,

Flo